# Bitmap too large. Tried All

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, out-of-memory

Guys I am facing this issue since 2 days straight. I want to pick an image from gallery and convert it to Base64 method. I have tried Picasso but my imageview is large. Can you please help me. I tried everything but out of memory is too much for me when converting it to bitmap and then to base64.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ProfilePic.getDrawable();
                            yourSelectedIBitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ProfilePic.getDrawable();
                            yourSelectedImage = drawable.getBitmap();mage = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Code which is converting this bitmap to Base64. Is there any possibility of skipping the bitmap and directly converting to Base64

```
private String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {

        Bitmap immagex = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
        //Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
        return imageEncoded;
    }
```

Profile Pic is name of Imageview.

**EDIT**: So guyz one of the ways is to use the large heap, but Google says you should not use that unless absolutely necessary. The other one that worked for me is the accepted answer. Now I came up with my own solution. In theory, I am using Picasso to load the image into image view. So what if I can extract the image from the ImageView. Not from URI or path, but from Imageview. This way you have an image which is already reduced by Picasso. Picasso provides **Callback** to for Success or failure. So on Success, you can access the cache memory of ImageView and extract the Bit map out of it.

I will post the code as an answer shortly. I tried it and even an image of 35Mb originally can be converted to bitmap without Out of memory exception.

So here is my ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52125006/6022584

Comment: Did u use large heap?

Comment: One of the way is to use that. and other is accepted one. but the best one is to use picasso. Wait I will post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to read the bitmap data with a buffer. Something like that :

```
private String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
  // get an InputStream
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos); 
  byte[] bitmapdata = baos.toByteArray();
  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);

  // prepare a buffer to read the inputStream
  byte[] buffer = new byte[10 * ONE_KIO];  // ONE_KIO = 1024
  int bytesRead;

  // prepare the stream to encode in Base64
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Base64OutputStream base64OutputStream = new Base64OutputStream(outputStream, Base64.DEFAULT);

  // read the inputStream
  while ((bytesRead = bais.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    base64OutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  base64OutputStream.close();

  // get the encoded result string
  return outputStream.toString();
}
```

Comment: Bro is it possible to give the code line by line. I am new to android. I am getting the Image URi from activity result

Comment: So can i put this one in on activity result?? I am very sorry but I am totally new plz

Comment: Thanks it worked, but there is an even better solution. See Edited Question

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code that worked. New Issue is the name of Activity for me

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //isImageFromGallery = true;
                //isImageSelected = true;
                ImagePath = data.getData();

                Picasso.get()
                        .load(ImagePath)
                        .resize(1024,1024)
                        .onlyScaleDown()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(picture, new Callback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) picture.getDrawable();
                                yourSelectedImage = drawable.getBitmap();
                                //isImageSelected = true;

                                Log.d("FileSize",Formatter.formatFileSize(NewIssue.this,
                                        yourSelectedImage.getByteCount()));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewIssue.this, "Could Not Load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

            }
        }
```