# Android: Bitmap too large. Nothing working except setting android:hardwareAccelerated to false

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-image

I have an Android application where I need to load an image in the imageView. I have tried every recommended solution but the app is still crashing on old Redmi devices. The exception, I'm getting is **trying to draw too large bitmap**. The stack trace I got on robo test is the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(268435456bytes) bitmap.
       FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.hkprog.captiongenerator, PID: 20296

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(268435456bytes) bitmap.

at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19337)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18254)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19345)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18254)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:5030)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19345)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4429)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18254)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1277)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19345)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18254)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.drawChild(FragmentContainerView.java:235)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.dispatchDraw(FragmentContainerView.java:223)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1975)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18245)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19052)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4301)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4085)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19345)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:792)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18254)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:678)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:684)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:792)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3164)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2964)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2502)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1482)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7124)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1008)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:804)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:994)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:7)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.-$$Nest$smsendSingleTap(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:21)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

The app is also crashing on some devices, by loading the images into imageview from the drawable folder. The image's size in drawable folder is less than 2mb.

The only way I'm able to fix this error is by adding the following line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

However, this is resulting in disabling all the elevations of CardView.

**Solutions, I've tried:**

**Loading a Scaled Down Version into Memory**

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize (BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}


Bitmap imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
            selectedImage);
InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);


final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

**Glide**

```
Glide.with(context).load(selectedImage).apply(
        new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
        .centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

**Picasso**

```
Picasso.get().load(selectedImage).resize(1080, 720)
        .onlyScaleDown()
        .into(imageView);
```

**Picasso: extracting the image from the ImageView and not from URI or path**

As suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52125006/6022584)

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(selectedImage)
        .resize(1024,1024)
        .onlyScaleDown()
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView, new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                //isImageSelected = true;

                Log.d("FileSize", Formatter.formatFileSize(getActivity(),
                        imageBitmap.getByteCount()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could Not Load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

All these solutions don’t seem to work. And app keep crashing on the older devices. Is there any way I could solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added the stacktrace.

Comment: i think this link will be helpful . https://stackoverflow.com/a/41502449/17861668

Comment: @BhavikKalsariya, I've tried this also. But it didn't work. Also I need to load images from the phone gallery as well.

Comment: Sorry @blackapps. I am printing the logs from robo test. I am not able to reproduce the issue on my device.

Comment: `Loading a Scaled Down Version into Memory` How much are you scaling down? You dont have to calculate that. You can just say do 4, 8 , 16, ... times.

Comment: It is pretty strange that setImageBitmap() is not in the stack trace.

Comment: @blackapps please refer to this link, https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap